# how do I put a while loop into a thread, using try with resources?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, syntax, try-with-resources

How do I put the `while` loop into the thread?

```
public class Weather {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        String host = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
        int port = 3000;
        int byteOfData;
        {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
                    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream ouputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                //also, a thread for reading from stdin
                Thread remoteOutputStream = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //while loop should go here
                        //   java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
                        //why does this error occur?
                    }
                };
                remoteOutputStream.start();
                while ((byteOfData = inputStream.read()) != -1) {  //put into thread
                    out.print((char) byteOfData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I put the `while` loop into the thread, it just throws `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed` because, presumably, of how `try with resources works`.  However, I don't know how to use a thread with this kind of try.

Because there **will be** multiple threads, one for reading the local InputStream and one for the remote OutputStream, it seems necessary to put the threads into the `try` and not vice versa..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the entire try with resources statement into the thread

```
final String host = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
final int port = 3000;

{
  Thread remote = new Thread()
  {
    @Override public void run()
    {
      try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
          InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
          OutputStream ouputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
          PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
          final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
      {
        int byteOfData;

        while ((byteOfData = inputStream.read()) != -1)
        { //put into thread
          out.print((char)byteOfData);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  remote.start();
```

Comment: doh, I was, as always, asking the wrong question.  that makes more sense, your way :)      Out of curiosity, assuming that's the solution, though, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because the `inputStream` and `byteOfData` are in a seperate thread

Comment: Hmm, I end up with a worse mess (so far).  Also, I need one thread for reading an open stream, and one thread for writing to an open stream.

Comment: What's the "worse mess"?

Comment: Then you could write to the `OutputStream` in the main thread and read from it in the spawned `Thread` I guess

Comment: The two answers are similar approach.  I'll keep working it, to get them to compile.  something subtle, at least to me, about try-catch.  I get many uncaught exceptions.

Comment: it should tell you the name of any uncaught exceptions, just catch them and deal with them.

Comment: got it running, thanks.  the syntax was confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

Something like (will probably need tidying up):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    String host = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
    int port = 3000;
    int byteOfData;
    {
            //also, a thread for reading from stdin
            Thread remoteOutputStream = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
                        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                        OutputStream ouputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                       while ((byteOfData = inputStream.read()) != -1) {  //put into thread
                           out.print((char) byteOfData);
                       }
                    } catch (CATCH EXCEPTIONS HERE) {
                       // Handle errors here
                    }
            };
            remoteOutputStream.start();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to separate threads then you will want something like a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), have one thread read and push to the queue - the other read pull from the queue and write.

I don't see any reason why you would want to have two threads to do this though.

Comment: One thread for remote, one thread for local.  And then passing messages between the threads....poor mans telnet client.

Comment: I get a ton of unreported exceptions, and don't know how to catch them.

Comment: If one was remote then it'd be a seperate program (or another copy of this), no extra thread